# create jumping effect for an object

Tags: javascript

here i created a grass object and it has two methods jump and fall.it jumps when user presses the up key on the keyboard.it jumps ,its alright.but i want it to fall back to its previous position..

i have created a keypressed variable which value is either true of false.it will determine the boundary how high the object can jump.

the object should fall back to its previous position after each jump.which i can't manage to do..**also jump is not realistic enough**...how this problems can be solved

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/Z9yKa/)

[link to the image](http://postimg.org/image/5xr35kj45/)

FULL CODE:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width=500;
canvas.height=500;
canvas.style.border="1px solid black";
var keypressed=true;
var img=new Image();
img.src="grass.jpg";
function grass(x,y){
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   this.image=img;

}

grass.prototype.draw=function(){
     ctx.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y);
}
grass.prototype.hop=function(){

   this.y-=200;
 keypressed=false;
}
grass.prototype.fall=function(){
  this.y+=200;
keypressed=true;

}
var grass1=new grass(30,450);
grass1.draw();
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
       if(keypressed && e.keyCode=='38'){

       grass1.hop();


       }
       if(grass1.y<0){
       return false;
       }else{
       grass1.draw(grass1.x,grass1.y);
        }
},false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: checkout the function setInterval. This should help with the animations for falling/jumping.

Comment: please suggest some suitable tags.i used object constructor to create objects.so i thought i should use the tag!!

Comment: @KJPrice i used a setInterval .but is not effecting the codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple version of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/B2SL5/

The key here is to use `requestAnimationFrame` (alternatively, you could use setInterval). We redraw the grass every frame (about 60 times a second). That way, when the grass moves (we call `grass.y--` to move it down), it shows on the screen. Then, we have a `velocity` variable to keep track of how fast we're going.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by interpolating either an existing `easing` or one that is derived to your liking and apply that by repeatedly increasing the independent variable of the function.

I suggest messing around here: http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm

Just a heads up. This can get complex very quickly.

PS: I won't be able to provide an exact solution as such things are very subjective.